# Copy a file, and recount the new state

Tags: javascript, copy, cypress

I am struggling with something at work. I am a newbie, so excuse me if I ask something easy. I coulnd't find it personally on the internet, so I hope you can provide me from (easily understandable)  information.

I am building an automated test. I am using Cypress.

At my work we have the following situation;

1) There is 1 file. We want to copy this. So we have to count the initial state first (1 file)

2) We will copy this file

3) We now have 2 files. We want to count that there are indeed  2 files

I have the following code for this;

```js
// count initialstate (1 file) = 
let InitialStateCopy = 
cy.getScoped('catalog-> item:case_type:link').contains('filename').should('have.length', 1 ) 

// press copy

// copy the file, execute actions here

// check if file is copied correctly (2 files)

let NewState = 
cy.getScoped('catalog-> item:case_type:link').contains('filename').should('have.length', 2 )
```

I get the message

CypressError: cy.contains() cannot be passed a length option because it will only ever return 1 element.

And I see that Cypress only finds 1 element.

Does somebody know how I can count how many objects there are? Which code should I use for this ? Basically, I just want to know how I can count elements on a page.

Answer (score 0):

[`cy.contains('blah')` will automatically assert that the element containing `blah` exists:](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Rules)

> `.contains()` will automatically retry itself until the element(s) exist in the DOM.

So you don't need to do a `.should('have.length', 1)` to assert this. The `.contains` itself performs an implicit assertion.

Cypress is trying to warn you that `.contains` [only returns 1 element](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Single-Element), so you might be doing something wrong if you're trying to assert on the length of it. In this case, you're trying to assert that `length` is `2`, which is impossible.

I don't know what your `.getScoped` is, but this just uses regular CSS syntax. To do what you're trying to do, try this [JQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), which works because Cypress uses JQuery's selector engine:

```js
cy.get(".catalog .item:contains('filename')").should('have.length', 2)
```

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-scope="catalog-item:case_type:link:contains("namefile")"]

  
expected '' to have a length of 2 but got 0

This is the code I used. I guess Cypress doesnt support it ?

Comment: @ErmanGultop your selector looks wrong. try `[data-scope="catalog-item:case_type:link"]:contains("namefile")` or `:contains("namefile")[data-scope="catalog-item:case_type:link"]`

Comment: It is supported: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1009#issuecomment-349475927